# windows phone 8.1 push notification

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I need to integrate push notification service in my app. I am using azure. In their documentation for connecting app to notification hub "WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed" package is used but its not present in windows phone 8.1. What is the alternative for this.

I have used following code to get channel

```
PushNotificationChannel channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

How can I register this channel with hub and then receive notification.

Answer (score 0):

Nuget Package [WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed/) is available for Windows Phone 8.1 Store Apps as well as Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight Apps.

You have to add the Package to your project via nuget.

Comment: sir its not installing. Following error is coming

Install-Package : Unable to find package 'WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your nuget. Also: As it is a 0.x version, you may check that nuget includes prerelease versions.

Comment: found the package. Thanks Kai.